# Update the_geom field with polygons from a different table using one common field

Tags: carto, geojson, sql, attribute-joins, update

Using CartoDB SQL API I'd like to: Update the_geom field in a table that has no spatial data by selecting the polygons from a table with spatial data and joining based on one common field..

In this particular case, the polygons are property boundaries or parcels and the common field in both tables is the "parcel_id" which is a unique identifier as a string

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_without_geoms_name SET the_geom = (SELECT a.the_geom FROM table_with_geoms as a WHERE table_without_geoms_name.parcel_id = a.parcel_id)
```

Of course, you'd need to change the name of your tables accordingly. :-)

Comment: haha yes of course :) - this is terrific! thanks for the help